# Is modifying v-model indirectly an anti pattern?

Tags: vue.js

In Vue 3 the following line of code produces an error:

```
<input v-model="modelValue[idx].name" v-for="(item, idx) in modelValue" :key="idx">
```

The error is the following:

```
error  Unexpected mutation of "modelValue" prop  vue/no-mutating-props
```

This makes sense, since modifying property values is considered an anti-pattern:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Prop-Mutation-deprecated

Yet the following line of code compiles and runs happily:

```
<input v-model="item.name" v-for="(item, idx) in modelValue" :key="idx">
```

I still modify the very same object, the only difference is that I refer to it indirectly. Is this OK, or is this an anti pattern that the linter fails to detect?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in the documentation:

> **Warning**
> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child component will affect the parent state and Vue is unable to warn you against this. As a general rule, you should avoid mutating any prop, including objects and arrays as doing so ignores one-way data binding and may cause undesired results.

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow